# How to encode the text into string in rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
unit = "Nm³/hr Air"
# => "Nm³/hr Air"
unit.html_safe?
# => false
```

I want the result of `unit.html_safe?` as `true` for to display in the view.

Thanks in advance

Comment: your unit value is static or dynamic?

Comment: Your string doesn't contain any HTML tags.

Comment: Even "<%= "<h1>hiiii</h1>".html_safe? %>" will return false, because of html_safe return behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Just do `unit.html_safe` in your view.

Comment: `html_safe` should be called when creating the string. For views there's the 'raw' helper.

Answer (score 1):

Calling html_safe on a String returns a new object that looks and acts like a String.

In your case, it's not returning string that why html_safe returns false.

Have a close look http://techspry.com/ruby_and_rails/html_safe-and-helpers-in-rails-3-mystery-solved/, i hope it will help you.